# How to skip empty cells using csv.DictWriter

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to anonymize data in CSV, however, I only want to do this for cells that are not empty. At present, my program adds anonymized data to all cells with the given row.

How can I skip empty the empty cells? Below is my program

```
import csv
from faker import Faker
from collections import defaultdict



def anonymize():
    "Anonymizes the given original data to anonymized form"
    faker = Faker()

    names = defaultdict(faker.name)
    emails = defaultdict(faker.email)

    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        with open(f"{filename}-anonymized_data.csv", "w") as o:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            writer = csv.DictWriter(o, reader.fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            for row in reader:
                    row["adult_First_Name"] = names[
                        row["adult_First_Name"]
                    ]
                    row["child_First_Name"] = names[
                        row["child_First_Name"]
                    ]
                    row["Adult - EMAIL ADDRESS"] = emails[row["Adult - EMAIL ADDRESS"]]
                    row["Parent - EMAIL ADDRESS"] = emails[row["Parent - EMAIL ADDRESS"]]
                    writer.writerow(row)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    anonymize()
```

Comment: I think this question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26621634/python-adding-a-blank-empty-column-csv). Not marking it as a duplicate because I'm not sure it's the same use case as OP's

Comment: @yorodm I believe that question is about adding blank columns, my question is in reards to skipping empty cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test each field before applying the fake value. A simpler approach would be to store the fields that need to be changed in a `fields` list along with which faker function to apply if needed:

```
import csv
from faker import Faker

def anonymize():
    "Anonymizes the given original data to anonymized form"
    faker = Faker()

    fields = [
        ("adult_First_Name", faker.name),
        ("child_First_Name", faker.name),
        ("Adult - EMAIL ADDRESS", faker.email),
        ("Parent - EMAIL ADDRESS", faker.email),
    ]

    with open(filename, "r") as f:
        with open(f"{filename}-anonymized_data.csv", "w", newline="") as o:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            writer = csv.DictWriter(o, reader.fieldnames)
            writer.writeheader()
            
            for row in reader:
                for field, fake in fields:
                    if row[field]:
                        row[field] = fake()
                
                writer.writerow(row)

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    anonymize()
```

Adding `newline=''` would stop extra blank lines in the output.